# Excel 2013 conditional formatting not working correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an issue with Excel 2013. The conditional formatting just will not work. I've got a `VLOOKUP` which pulls data from another worksheet. Then I want to use conditional formatting on that data. The conditions are `=$N$3>30` to color the cell red and `=$N$3<30` to color the cell green. It just stays permanently red or permanently green. I've tried every solution and possible work around I can think of and nothing works.

Does any one have any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAvkq.png)

Comment: I can't tell enough from your post to provide any suggestions. From what I can see, you are saying that if the value in cell N3 is greater than 30, color some unspecified cells green, if cell N3 is less than 30, color those cells red, and if the value is equal to 30, do nothing. You don't explain what is happening instead, you don't say what cells you are trying to color, and the image doesn't show the value in cell N3, so the image doesn't give any help at all. So, please clarify your problem and include the information that we need to have to be able to solve it.

Comment: As a general rule, using the word "work" anywhere in your explanation of your problem pretty much guarantees that nobody else will be able to understand it. You're the only person who knows what "work" means to you. :)

Comment: Oops sorry about that it seems the text i added to the picture isn't there. So the box N3 which has the value 11.46 in it is the one that i have formatted. There are multiple other as well but lets focus on that for now. You can clearly see that it is below 30 yet it is colored red when it should be colored green. I am having this issue across multiple conditional formatting formulas, even the most basic ones as above. Does that explain it better?

Comment: It does. What is the currently selected cell in this image, please?

Comment: The cell is N3 which has a value of 11.46 currently

Comment: It doesn't look selected to me. If it were, it should have a heavy line around it. In fact, there's nothing in your image that indicates what the currently selected cell is, which is the one to which your formula applies. Are you sure that you're not actually looking at the formatting for another cell?

Comment: I can assure you that it's selected, it's just that i've clicked to open paint and it looks deselected. I've updated the photo on the post so that you can clearly see N3 is selected. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Value in your N3 (or in column N), is a text thus color is red. Add double dash (--) to your VLookup function to convert the result to number. Your formula should be *=IFERROR(--VLOOKUP(A3,...* (complete the formula).

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! I thought it must be something to do with the Vlookup data because it was the only columns that did it, however i couldnt any information further about Vlookup. Where did you find out about this for future reference so i can learn more?

Comment: I did not google it. I noticed that values in column N is left aligned so I re-created your situation by setting N3 to text and it turned red but green when it is number.

Comment: I missed that! Good call.